# what is going on with the 2 mo old morning struggle?

Tags: sleep, newborn

2 mo old baby - sleeps very well at night, 6 -7 hours with 1 feeding, then immediately slumps over again.

He does this thing in the morning around 6,7am, where he is all squirming all over, his face all scrunched up, and pivot around his torso, with his arms and legs flailing every which way and is half crying, and half whining. His eyes remain closed the entire time. He does this for an hour-ish. He doesn't really wake up before then even if I shake him a little, or pinch him a little. Once he is truly awake, and his eye open, the squirming stops. He's just normal and all sparkly eyed and smiley.

What is going on there? Does anyone else have the morning struggle?

Comment: Starting to dream, perhaps?

Comment: Is he laying down, being held, or same thing no matter what position? I wonder if there's some kind of reflux thing.

Comment: What is your concern? Is the baby gaining well? Reaching developmental milestones? Does he respond to cuddling or feeding? (Most babies can nurse without waking fully) In terms of expectations, your baby is already sleeping longer than most infants at that age.

Comment: Colic, perhaps? Whatever it is that's going on... perhaps you'd both feel better if you put him in a carrier for a little chest to chest snooze during that funny hour.

Comment: Does swaddling help at all?  Our daughter responded well to being wrapped up in the early months.  It seemed to be a real comfort.

Comment: how long between eating?  Those hours are really long for someone so young (imo).  My daughters were doing 4 hours per sleep at that age, and their food capacity was the driving factor there.  After they had more body-mass they slept more through the night.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, congratulations on the new baby! \o/
Before I begin, let me just say that if you have concerns about the little one from a health perspective, it is always a good idea to raise this with your health visitor (if you have one) or the doctor if it is concerning you.

With that out of the way, our youngest son had something similar when he was a little older (at around 6 months or so). 
His was a combination of two things:

- Bouts of constipation and / or indegestion
  Our littl'un would feed in the night and then would become agitated around an hour or so later due the position lying down where he had developed trapped air in his tummy. A good back rub and burp helped with that.
  He did also suffer from constipation as well for a time which caused a lot of wriggling about and discomfort.
- Night-terrors
  "Night terrors" are very common and the term can sound worse than it actually is, since effectively what is happening here is that the child's mind is processing their experiences in the subcconscious. Often this can result in "whining" or "light crying" - our oldest son used to have these on a regular basis.

Either way, if it is something that continues and is concerning you, you should certainly take baby along to see the doctor, if only for your own peace of mind! :-)